# resulting .AVI files are much larger than the input .PNGs

Tags: python, opencv, compression, video-compression

I want an easy way to join multiple timestamped screenshots into a video file of any format (like mt4 or avi) with Python.

For this, I used CV2, but the problem is that the resulting .AVI files are way larger than the input PNGs. Like 400 input pngs that weight 20 mb produce a 500 mb file, which is absurd.

```
def movie(image_folder):
video_name = image_folder.split("/")[-2] + ".avi"

# find images
images = sorted([img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".png")])

# get height, width, layers of the first image
frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
height, width, layers = frame.shape

# creates video file
# second parameter is the fourcc (4-character code used for image compression)
# third parameter is the frame rate
# forth parameter is the size of resulting video file
video = cv2.VideoWriter("movies/" + video_name, 0, 1, (width, height))

for image in images:
    file_path = os.path.join(image_folder, image)
    # adds each screenshot to the nascent movie
    video.write(cv2.imread(file_path))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

What should I do to make the resulting file have the same (or a bit larger) size as the input PNGs?

Comment: learn about compression. you didn't specify any. why are you surprised that the (uncompressed) result is larger?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz does cv2 have a way to compress avi files?

Comment: Png is very good in compressing regions of constant color, which is often the case in artificial images like computer desktops or video game backgrounds. Depending on the video codec it might not be able to come close to that compression rate. You can specify the video encoder with a fourcc code in VideoWriter parameters.

Comment: of course opencv has a way to compress *video*. just specify a codec by passing an acceptable "fourcc" value to `VideoWriter`. you didn't do that, you just passed `0`. try `VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")` for something that always works, or `*"avc1"` to get H.264. -- png uses lossless compression. most video compression is lossy because that gives better compression for very little perceptible degradation. in principle, _lossy_ compression can do everything that lossless compression can do, so lossy compression will very likely compress better than PNG (which is lossless).